# Is there a way to distinguish between the 38mm and 42mm apple watch versions?

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch, xcode-6.2

I'm programming an App for the Apple Watch and I have to display certain content differently for the 38mm and 42mm version.

With `UIDevice.currentDevice().model` you can get the model of the iphone (eventhough it only Displays *"iPhone Simulator"* in Xcode, but you get the idea).

Is there a way to get the model of the Apple Watch, so 38mm or 42mm, with a similar function?

Comment: Remember that you cannot layout your interface programmatically, which means that you have to have the same for both versions of the watch.

Answer (score 8):

I found the answer! If you are interested:

```
WKInterfaceDevice.currentDevice().screenBounds.size
```

will give you `(136.0,170.0)` for the 38mm version of Apple Watch and `(156.0,195.0)` for the 42mm version of Apple Watch. With this information you can distinguish between these devices.